# sorting a csv file according to column in C++

Tags: c++, sorting, csv

I been given a task to sort a csv file depending on the users input

The data looks like this:

```
California,USA,65,76,65,67
Paris,France,78,65,97,87
Tokyo,Japan,56,78,67,87
New York,USA,54,65,67,44,67
```

Or basically the column represents

```
City,Country,q1 average temperature, q2 average temperature, q3 , q4
```

my task is to sort this according to columns:  city as column 1, country column 2 , and so on... depending on the user input.

so if the user input is `1dec` that means it will be sort by 1st column(alphabetically in this case) and prints the sorted data

for the example above it would print as:

```
Tokyo,Japan,56,78,67,87
Paris,France,78,65,97,87
New York,USA,65,67,67,44,67
California,USA,65,76,65,67
```

the user can also enter multiple  inputs like `2asc,3dec,4dec` this means that, the column 2 will be the first to be sorted in ascending order and if they have similar data in that column, the 3rd column will be use displaying them in descending order, then if its still the same use column 4.

for the example above if called using `2asc,3dec,4dec` it would print as:

```
Paris,France,78,65,97,87
Tokyo,Japan,56,78,67,87
California,USA,65,76,65,67
New York,USA,65,67,67,44,67
```

My question is, How should I approach this problem?
What is the best data structure should I use?

PS. Not really asking for code sample, but I am just asking for some hints
or an approach if you will be given this kind of problem

Comment: Not going to do your homework for you.. what have you got so far?

Comment: @Bgie , sorry, I should have written it, but I am not asking for code. I am just asking for an approach on how to solve. usually, I dont start coding, if I dont know how to approach the problem. I am just asking for a hint..

Comment: Create a struct that contains your csv row, put it into a stl container, create a functor that check lexicographic order between two instances of your struct and use the `std::sort` in your container.

Comment: @Jepessen hi, thanks for the hint. What STL container would you recommend to use?

Comment: A struct for every row could work, but since you need to index them by column number, a vector of vectors might be helpful.

Comment: @XDProgrammer 1) Jepessen's advice seems to be exactly what you need. 2) There's one empiric rule: if you don't know what type of container is better - use `std::vector`

Comment: @Bgie thanks, yah it seems vectors are best to use, originally was thinking array of structs.

Comment: `std::vector` is good, but more generally you need an ordered container. Avoid thinks like `unordered_map` that are not good by definition.

Comment: The sorting is the slightly tricky bit: I suggest that if you put the data into a `struct X`, add a function `int compareColumn(int column_num, const X& rhs) const` that returns `-1` if `*this`'s value in column `column_num` is less than `rhs`'s, `0` if they're equal, else `1`. You can then write a `bool less(int column_num_A, bool ascending_A, int column_num_B, bool ascending_B, int column_num_C, bool ascending_C);` that uses the `compareColumn` functions three times.  (Could generalise further by taking a `vector<pair<int, bool>>` of column numbers/ascending-flags.)

Comment: Just one caution if you do choose to try a `vector<vector<string>>` - you may need some extra handling of number columns to avoid `string`'s lexical comparisons: e.g. `"10" < "2"`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method you could use, hope you find it intuitive

1. Read the data and put it into a unsorted vector with objects (classes) that represents the real world data.
2. Parse the user input to decide the column and sort order
3. Use a simple sorting algorithm such as selection sort to add the data to a sorted vector.
4. iterate over the sorted vector and output the result.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, How should I approach this problem? What is the best
>   data structure should I use?

You should use several data structure but if you use a vector to store the input list (and if it is quite big), you'd better to use **reserve** method so that you'll avoid to reallocate the vector many times.

Another interesting point is to **apply repeatedly the ordering criteria in the reverse order** so that you'll have the output ordered following the multiple criteria in an easy way.

If you worth about performance you should use a more complex approach.